# WooCommerce.NET add product with category/subcategory

Tags: c#, woocommerce-rest-api

I am looking for some "inspiration", on how to add a product to my WC store.

I can add a simple product:

```
Product prod = new Product()
{
sku = SKU,
name = Name,
description = Description,
regular_price = Price,
manage_stock = true,
stock_quantity = quantity,
};

wc.Product.Add(prod).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

But how do I add this product to category, when I only have a category name?

Additional problem is that I have a category structure, where many sub categories have the same name.

Example:

> main category: MALE sub categories: shoes, t-shirts, underwear,
>   accessories
>
> main category: FEMALE sub categories: shoes, t-shirts, underwear,
>   accessories
>
> main category: CHILDREN sub categories: shoes, t-shirts, underwear

I was importing the products database via CSV, where I named the category:

> CATEGORY>SUBCATEGORY

So? Any Ideas?

Thanks!

EDIT:
From the answer of Matthias S. I have  got some good insight. But I would need a more universal solution.
I need to get the proper category id, from only the names of categories.
I am thinking in a direction of loops, where I would:
1. loop: find top category by name
-2. loop: find firs subcategory by name
--3. loop: find next subcategory by name
---- ...
Would that be even possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A category is more than just a name for WC. You need to create the same category tree inside your shop as you have on your input side. A WC category therefor has an unique ID, the display name and a parentID.

For your given example you could create the MALE category via api

```
ProductCategory newCategoryMale = new ProductCategory
{
    name = "MALE"
};
ProductCategory maleCategory = await wooCommerce.Category.Add(newCategoryMale)
```

and the returned category will have an id you can then use to create the sub categories.

```
ProductCategory newCategoryShoes = new ProductCategory
{
    name = "shoes",
    parent = maleCategory.id
};
ProductCategory shoes = await wooCommerce.Category.Add(newCategoryShoes)
```

Now that you have the category tree structure as well as the related ids, you can create your products straight with the categories assigned.

```
Product prod = new Product()
{
    sku = SKU,
    name = Name,
    description = Description,
    regular_price = Price,
    manage_stock = true,
    stock_quantity = quantity,
    categories = new List<ProductCategoryLine>
    {
        new ProductCategoryLine
        {
            id = shoes.id
        }
    }
};
```

**Edit:**

To get the id of an already existing category you may use

```
List<ProductCategory> existingCategories = await wooCommerce.Category.GetAll();
```

to get all categories already setup in your shop.
When looking for Male->Shoes you need to search that list for an root level category named "MALE" and find a category named "shoes" where the parentId equals your male-categorys id.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for you fast response! Now I understand this better how to add product with category id. Also adding a category is more clear now, and it will come in handy later, when I need to add a new category. I still can't find an answer how to find the correct id of existing category, from just a top category name and sub category name. Can you update your answer with that? Also - is there a good documentation about Woocommerce.NET?